# Loops aninhados e incrementação

Tags: javascript, loop

Estou estudando JavaScript pelo livro da casa do código 
e tem um desafio envolvendo loops aninhados, no qual eu tenho que desenhar isso:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
```

Usando esse código:

```js
for(var Linha=0;Linha<10;Linha=Linha+1){
    for(var Coluna=0;Coluna<10;Coluna=Coluna+1){
        document.write("*")
    }
    document.write("<br>")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para atingir esse objetivo só precisa de alterar a condição de paragem no `for` das colunas, para que pare no numero a seguir à linha corrente.

Pode visualizar assim:

- Na primeira linha, a linha 0, vai até 1 e escreve 1 caretere
- Na segunda, a linha 1, vai até 2, e por isso escreve 2 careteres

E por ai em diante.

Exemplo:

```js
for(var Linha=0;Linha<10;Linha=Linha+1){
    for(var Coluna=0;Coluna<Linha + 1;Coluna=Coluna+1){
        //                    ^--- Linha + 1 em vez de 10
        document.write("*")
    }
    document.write("<br>")
}
```

Na verdade como você quer apenas repetir os asteriscos uma determinada quantidade de vezes já tem o método [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) da string que faz isso, o que simplifica bastante a lógica:

```js
for(var Linha=0;Linha<10;Linha=Linha+1){
    document.write("*".repeat(Linha + 1) + "<br>")
}
```